# How to dynamically call css path in head section of an html page

Tags: javascript, css

I want css path in the head section of an HTMl page, the path should come through an external JS file as I want to add multiple no. of css.

Answer (score 2):

```
function addCSS() {
        var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (!headtg) {
            return;
        }
        var linktg = document.createElement('link');
        linktg.type = 'text/css';
        linktg.rel = 'stylesheet';
        linktg.href = 'CSS/RoundCorners.css';
        linktg.title = 'Rounded Corners';
        headtg.appendChild(linktg);
    }
```

Source: http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/how-to-add-css-link-programmatically.html

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ... Is there any way to use multiple css so I can change the theme. Actually I was looking for the theme changes through css based JS but I stuck on the 1st step which is now solved as u help me...Thank you once again.

Comment: @amolD You'd have to change an existing `link` element rather than append a new one. CoDe ADDict has already posted a link for switching stylesheets http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/